# How would you create a code using Python using the following information?

Tags: python

When bakers get together for a party, they like to eat pastries. A bakers' party is successful when
the number of pastries is between 40 and 60, inclusive. Unless it is the weekend, in which case
there is no upper bound on the number of pastries. Use the function design recipe to develop a
function named bakers_party. The function takes two arguments. The first argument is the
number of pastries (an integer). The second argument is True if it's the weekend, False if the
day is a weekday. The function returns True if a party with the given arguments is successful,
otherwise it will return False.

Comment: SO is a forum for technical questions. Please refer to the article [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would create it by reading the text, understanding it, thinking about a solution, and then writing some code in my text editor to implement that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bakers_party(no_pastr,weekend):
    """ <Return whether the baker's party will be successful.>
    @type no_pastr : int, weekend : bool
    @rtype bool
    """
    if not weekend and no_pastr >= 40 and <= 60:
        return True
    elif weekend and no_pastr >= 40:
        return True        
    else:
        return False
```

There you go. Hope you get a good grade.

Comment: You forgot about the [function design recipe](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~ahchinaei/teaching/20165/csc148/function_design_recipe.pdf) requirement.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thank you, didn't know that!